# How to save a long type data with Persistent Object on Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have a class DataContext to save data by Persistent Object.

```
DataContext data = new DataContext();
data.set("edit",myEditField.getText(); // ok
```

but

```
data.set("date",myDateField.getDate()); // not accept for save long type.
```

How can I save myDateField with Persistent object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlackBerry persistent objects can only store objects and a long is a primitive.  Just use the [Long](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/java/lang/Long.html) wrapper object and store that with your PersistentObject.

Comment: @Jonathan: is the `Date` class persistable?

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB based on the test I just did, no Date is not persistable.  My mistake.  I've edited my answer to not include that part.